# ChartJS - Highlight Weekends and Lowest and Highest Values

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS and I'd like to highlight all Saturdays and Sundays as a different colour - I'd also light to highlight the highest and lowest values in the chart.

Is this possible?

Fiddle so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/3wku56Lq/

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['14 May 2019 (Tue)', '15 May 2019 (Wed)', '16 May 2019 (Thu)', '17 May 2019 (Fri)', '18 May 2019 (Sat)', '19 May 2019 (Sun)', '20 May 2019 (Mon)', '21 May 2019 (Tue)', '22 May 2019 (Wed)', '23 May 2019 (Thu)', '24 May 2019 (Fri)', '25 May 2019 (Sat)', '26 May 2019 (Sun)', '27 May 2019 (Mon)', '28 May 2019 (Tue)', '29 May 2019 (Wed)', '30 May 2019 (Thu)', '31 May 2019 (Fri)', '01 Jun 2019 (Sat)', '02 Jun 2019 (Sun)', '03 Jun 2019 (Mon)', '04 Jun 2019 (Tue)', '05 Jun 2019 (Wed)', '06 Jun 2019 (Thu)', '07 Jun 2019 (Fri)'],
    datasets: [{
        data: [25738, 25261, 25499, 24178, 12400, 13356, 26033, 26588, 25018, 22972, 21702, 11232, 11617, 14308, 24212, 23949, 23708, 21511, 11545, 13836, 25536, 26824, 0, 0, 0],
        label: "Impressions",
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(199, 199, 199, 0.7)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(199, 199, 199)',
        fill: true
      }
    ]
  },
options: {
            tooltips: {
              callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        var value = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
                        value = value.toString();
                        value = value.split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/);
                        value = value.join(',');
                        return value;
                    }
              } // end callbacks:
            }, //end tooltips
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true,
                        userCallback: function(value, index, values) {
                            // Convert the number to a string and splite the string every 3 charaters from the end
                            value = value.toString();
                            value = value.split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/);
                            value = value.join(',');
                            return value;
                        }
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can highlight weekends using `map` functions:

http://jsfiddle.net/75apft3m/

Also, you can do the same with the lowest and highest value.
But for this you must store that arrays somewhere.
Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/75apft3m/1/

Just use `Math.max.apply(null, dataArray)`
and `Math.min.apply(null, dataArray)` to find highest and lowest values :)